# How to install r package GRanges on Linux Centos

Tags: r, linux, centos7, bioconductor

I just want to install the Bioconductor package GenomicRanges in R, but that doesn't work. There are about 25 warnings.

```
> biocLite("GRanges")

> warnings()
1: package ‘GRanges’ is not available (for R version 3.3.1)
2: In system2(cmd0, args, env = env, stdout = outfile, stderr = outfile) :
Systemaufruf fehlgeschlagen: Nicht genügend Hauptspeicher verfügbar
3: In install.packages(update[instlib == l, "Package"], l,  ... :
installation of package ‘DBI’ had non-zero exit status
4: In system2(cmd0, args, env = env, stdout = outfile, stderr = outfile) :
Systemaufruf fehlgeschlagen: Nicht genügend Hauptspeicher verfügbar
5: In install.packages(update[instlib == l, "Package"], l,  ... :
installation of package ‘jsonlite’ had non-zero exit status
6: In system2(cmd0, args, env = env, stdout = outfile, stderr = outfile) :
Systemaufruf fehlgeschlagen: Nicht genügend Hauptspeicher verfügbar
7: In install.packages(update[instlib == l, "Package"], l,  ... :
installation of package ‘limma’ had non-zero exit status
8: In system2(cmd0, args, env = env, stdout = outfile, stderr = outfile) :
Systemaufruf fehlgeschlagen: Nicht genügend Hauptspeicher verfügbar
9: In install.packages(update[instlib == l, "Package"], l,  ... :
installation of package ‘mgcv’ had non-zero exit status
10: In system2(cmd0, args, env = env, stdout = outfile, 
11: In install.packages(update[instlib == l, "Package"], l,  ... :
installation of package ‘psych’ had non-zero exit status
12: In system2(cmd0, args, env = env, stdout = outfile, stderr = outfile) 
:Systemaufruf fehlgeschlagen: Nicht genügend Hauptspeicher verfügbar
13: In install.packages(update[instlib == l, "Package"], l,  ... :
installation of package ‘Rcpp’ had non-zero exit status
14: In system2(cmd0, args, env = env, stdout = outfile, stderr = 
outfile) :Systemaufruf fehlgeschlagen: Nicht genügend Hauptspeicher  
verfügbar
15: In install.packages(update[instlib == l, "Package"], l,  ... :
installation of package ‘pdftools’ had non-zero exit status
16: In system2(cmd0, args, env = env, stdout = outfile, stderr = 
outfile) :Systemaufruf fehlgeschlagen: Nicht genügend Hauptspeicher   
verfügbar
.....
```

and so on....

I think that there are some packages missing, which I have to install on Linux Centos. But I don't know which packages are missing and how I can do that. 
Could anybody help?

Comment: Do you mean the package `GenomicRanges`? Then use `source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("GenomicRanges")`

Comment: I already tried that, but the warnings above came. I think I have to do some code in the terminal? @J_F